# How do I group this array and make a Dictionary index list in alphabetical order

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Here's my array

```
var contacts = [
    ExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, names: ["Hong Kong", "Bangkok, Thailand", "London, UK", "Singapore", "Bali, Indonesia", "Dubai, United Arab Emirates", "Paris, France", "New York City, US", "Milan, Italy", "Vienna, Austria", "Shenzhen, China", "Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia", "Phuket, Thailand", "Rome, Italy", "Tokyo, Japan", "Lisbon, Portugal", "Istanbul, Turkey", "Seoul, South Korea", "Amsterdam, Netherlands", "Guangzhou, China", "Prague, Czech Republic", "Mecca, Saudi Arabia", "Rio De Janeiro, Brazil", "Mumbai, India", "Barcelona, Spain", "Pattaya, Thailand", "Shanghai, China", "Antalya, Turkey", "Las Vegas, US"].map{ Contact(name: $0, hasFavorited: false) }),
]
```

Here's my struct variables on a different swift file

```
import Foundation

struct ExpandableNames {
    var isExpanded: Bool
    var names: [Contact]
     //let names: String

}

struct Contact {
    let name: String
    var hasFavorited: Bool
}
```

Comment: By the way its in a uitableview

Comment: Sorry I don’t see what you edited?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question, what do you want to group by and what do you mean with a dictionary index list?

Comment: I want to put this array into section index list in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrYourCities:[String] = ["Hong Kong", "Bangkok", "Thailand", "London", "UK", "Bangladesh"] //Your cities' array here

let allFirstAlphabets = arrYourCities.map({$0.first!})

let arrIndexList = uniq(source: allFirstAlphabets).sorted(by: <) // Your desired output ["B", "H", "L", "T", "U"]
```

*Helper Function to get the unique array so that dictionary index's alphabets don't get duplicated*

```
func uniq<S : Sequence, T : Hashable>(source: S) -> [T] where S.Iterator.Element == T {
            var buffer = [T]()
            var added = Set<T>()
            for elem in source {
                if !added.contains(elem) {
                    buffer.append(elem)
                    added.insert(elem)
                }
            }
            return buffer
    }
```